# Problems With Else If Statments

Tags: php, if-statement

Ok so what I want to happen is when a user is logged out my script should check the url for the code 2 and display to the user they have been logged out. If 1 There password or username was wrong and 3 Unsure how they got there. It pulls the correct number but will only display the message for 1. I don't know whats wrong :/

```
<?php
$err = $_GET['err'];
echo $err;//Proof the code is getting number
if ($err = "1") {
echo '<center><span class="error-box">'; echo "Whoops! Wrong Username or Password. Please try again.</span></center>";
} 
elseif ($err = '2') {
echo '<center><span class="info-box">'; echo "You Have Been Succesfully Logged Out.</span></center>";
} 
else {
echo '<center><span class="info-box">'; echo "Whoops! Somthing funny happened and were not quite sure what your trying to do. Please try again.</span></center>";
}
?>
```

Comment: you need to change all the = because it's an assignment operator

there is == comparison operator and it compares only the value without caring about the type

like 1 as integer when you use ==  to "1" as a string it returns ture

=== it compares the value and the type both

like $var1 = 1; and $var2 = "2"; if you used === it will return false, and if you used == it will return true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because comparison operator is `==`, not `=`.

So you need to have

```
if ($err == "1") {
```

Comment: also in php or c many people recommend use if ("1" == $err)  instead  if ("1" == $err)

Comment: There we go, Thank you so much!

Comment: @iMysak: I wouldn't say that many, but indeed, some people recommend doing that (though it is a protection from a very obvious mistake that usually detected very soon)

Comment: @Tyler Radlick: a typo-like mistake of using `=` instead of `==`

Comment: @TylerRadlick - It works because `if( "1" == $var)` is valid syntax, but `if( "1" = $var)` means you'd assign a variable to a constant, which is not valid. It's a way to represent `if` statements to guarantee fixing these typos. That being said, I still prefer the other way, as IMO it is more readable.